# Need to develop a Device Driver, which when installed on a system would create multiple Virtual serial port

Tags: wdf, umdf

This is my first Windows device driver and I have been assigned a task to develop a Windows device driver from scratch. When the user installs this driver on a windows PC it would ask the user, during the installation process, to enter the number of virtual serial port that user requires & after installation of the driver the number of virtual port desired by the user shall be created. Then the user connects his customized printer to the windows PC via USB port. The user should be able to send data to the printer through the Hyper terminal by selecting any of the newly created Virtual serial port at 9600 baud rate, 8 data bit, No parity and 1 stop bit.

Now to get started I am using a windows 7 system on which I have installed Visual Studio 2015 along with Windows Driver Kit 10 form the MSDN website. I have also downloaded the Windows drivers sample codes form the GITHUB this sample soce base contains a virtualSerial UMDF project under serial/Svirtualserial2. This project file contained 2 projects one being the Virtualserial2 project and the other is a FakeModem project so I deleted the FakeModem project (as its was of no use for me) and successfully compiled the source/VirtualSerial2 sample code. after compilation a .dll (as UDMF drivers have .dll extensions) file gets generated in the debug folded but I don't get any .exe for this driver so I am not sure how can I install this driver on my system.

I was also going through this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/dn745911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 that list the process to debug a UMDF driver using WinDbg, in an example it also asks us to run the .exe so my first question is how do I need to generate a .exe file of my driver & test it on a system.

Along with this I have one more query. after I install my driver on the target system (Windows 7 32 bit I need to link it to the hyper terminal). So that I will be able to send the Commands & data to my printer through the hyper terminal and my driver will be responsible to take the data from the hyper terminal and send it to my printer through USB. How can I do that?

Am I going in the right direction?